# Drag and drop image upload Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Any jquery plugins or raw code available for "drag and drop" image uploading? Like as we see in [Gmail](http://mail.google.com) file attachment.

Comment: Did you care to google?

Comment: that's an HTML5 feature, take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12954529/jquery-html5-file-drag-and-drop

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=drag+and+drop+upload&oq=drag+and+drop+upload&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l2j69i60l3.3015j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=jquery+plugins+or+raw+code+available+for+%22drag+and+drop%22+image+uploading&safe=off

Answer (score 11):

[Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/about/)

[Blueimp](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload)

[Fine Uploader](http://fineuploader.com/)

These are a few that I have used and have worked fine.

You could have just googled it and come up with many results.